# how can i compare a .reg file with a windows registry using perl

Tags: perl

Can I compare a .reg file with a Windows registry using Perl. If yes, how can I perform that?
I searched in several sites, but couldn't get a proper response.
Your help will be highly appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Win32::TieRegistry](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Win32-TieRegistry-0.26/lib/Win32/TieRegistry.pm) module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ActiveState's [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl), it will include a lot of the Windows packages that you need for things like registry reading, etc.

I recommend looking at <strike>`Win32:Registry`</strike><sup>1</sup> `Win32::TieRegistry`. You can look at a key in our `.reg` file (it's a text file), and then open that same key in the registry and compare the values. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/lib/Win32/TieRegistry.html).

Also, I believe registry files are in Windows INI file format. If that's the case, take a look at [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.79/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm). This will help you read in your `.reg` file and go through it line by line. I've used it, and it's pretty simple to use. `Config::IniFiles` isn't a standard Perl module, so you have to download it from CPAN. However, ActivePerl comes with [Config::Ini](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/lib/ActiveState/Config/INI.html). I haven't used that one, but it looks like it might help.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've been informed by Dmitry Mina that `Win32::Registry` is obsolete. I now see it says so in the documentation and the documentation recommends to use `Win32::TieRegistry`.

Comment: CPAN page of Win32::Registry module says that it is obsolete and Win32::TieRegistry should be used instead...

Comment: @DmitryMina - Sorry, I am just familiar Win32::Registry which now that I think about it, I first used back in the Windows NT days. Maybe Win32::Registry isn't the only thing that's _obsolete_ around here. Excuse me, while I tell some kids to get off my lawn. I'll update my post.